# Django Concat columns with integers and strings

Tags: sql, django

I have run into an issue using attempting to add values from two different columns together in a query, namely that some of them contain numbers. This means that the built in [Concat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) does not work as it requires strings or chars.

Considering how one can cast variables as other datatypes in SQL I don't see why I wouldn't be able to do that in Django.

```
cast(name as varchar(100))
```

I would assume that one would do it as follows in Django using the Concat function in combination with [Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#cast).

```
queryset.annotate(new_col=Concat('existing_text_col', Cast('existing_integer_col', TextField())).get())
```

The above obviously does not work, so does anyone know how to actually do this?

The use case if anyone wonders are sending jenkins urls saved as fragments as a whole. So one url would be:

```
base_url: www.something.com/
url_fragment: name/
url_number: 123456
```

Comment: Is there any reason to do this in SQL rather than directly in Django? ie `os.path.join(item.base_url, item.url_fragment, str(item.url_number))`?

Comment: No reason to do it in SQL when having installed a framework. Sorry if I wrote my question oddly. I just gave an example in SQL since I am more comfortable with it than Django. I don't recognize os.path so I will have to look into that, but perhaps it's just what I need @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a serializer that inherits from the base serializer that contains the urls fragments and a lot of other things. In it I made a MethodField for my complete url and defined a getter function that loaded in the different fragments and added them together. I also redeclared the fragmented fields to None.

The code inside the new serializer is:

```
complete = serpy.MethodField("get_copmlete")

serverUrl = serpy.Field(attr=None, call=False, required=False)
jobName = serpy.Field(attr=None, call=False, required=False)
buildNumber = serpy.Field(attr=None, call=False, required=False)

def get_complete(self, obj):
    return obj.server_url + obj.job_name + '/' + str(obj.build_number)
```